# And Condition with join is similar to where condition after join

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

Is it similar to have and condition with join and where condition after join?

for example

will it give me same result for below two queries

```
1) SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM language_message_mapping lm
 LEFT JOIN user_profiles up ON lm.user_profile_id_fk=user_profile_id_pk 
  AND lm.user_profile_id_fk IS NOT NULL

2) SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM language_message_mapping lm
LEFT JOIN user_profiles up ON lm.user_profile_id_fk=user_profile_id_pk 
where lm.user_profile_id_fk IS NOT NULL
```

I want to update rows which I get from above query
please tell me below update query is correct or not

```
UPDATE language_message_mapping lm 
LEFT JOIN user_profiles up ON lm.user_profile_id_fk=user_profile_id_pk 
SET lm.user_account_id_fk=up.user_account_id_fk
AND lm.user_profile_id_fk IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I think you could test this for yourself. :-(

Comment: I tested it , but when i execute update query it gives me different count andselect query gives different count when I used and condition with join

Comment: Well that tells you something then

Comment: that's what i want to know is both query works as same behavior or not

Comment: only put fields covered by an index into the on-clause. the rest should go to the where clause. the on-clause will create the join and the where clause will filter the result. for that reason you get a higher count in your first query since the left join will show all rows of lm-table that match the where clause no matter what the on-clause says. the second query filters the result because of the where-clause(as mentioned) therefore the count is lower

Comment: So, clearly not. There's your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the same for a `left join` (it would be the same for an `inner join` though).

The first query gets **all records** from the first table and adds data from the second table according to your conditions in the `JOIN ON` clause.

The second query gets **not all records** of the first table - only the data that matches the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The first query will apply the `lm.user_profile_id_fk IS NOT NULL` statement in the join operation of both tables, so it will exclude the rows where `lm.user_profile_id_fk IS NOT NULL`.

The second query will do the join, and once the join is applied for all rows will extract those where `lm.user_profile_id_fk IS NOT NULL`

About performance it depens of table size, indexes, and others.

Answer (score 0):

NO, they are not same at all. your first query will give a proper effect of a `OUTER JOIN` whereas the second query will be eventually same as `INNER JOIN`

For an `INNER JOIN` this wouldn't make any difference though